# Android - how to return to previous activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application there are many activities, if the user press the back button at any activity it will go to final activity where there are buttons for rate this app, feedback, Facebook etc. are present. It is possible for me to go back to previous activity when a button is pressed from the last activity. Also in manifest i gave android:noHistory="true" to all   activities.

For ex. if the user is in A activity if he presses back button, it will go to final activity from there if he presses a button it should go back to activity A. similarly for other activities. Is it possible?

i finally decide to go back only to the first activity when a button is pressed at the last activity, i used the following code.

```
Button first = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first);
    first.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(last.this,first.class));
            finish();

        }
    });
```

As i removed android:noHistory="true" in manifest for the first activity it keep on repeating.

how to stop this. where should i call the finish() in the first activity

Comment: its a good practice to respond to answers you received

Comment: sorry for my respond. Any how i solved it. i forget to call finish for another onclicklistner in the activity

Comment: `Also in manifest i gave android:noHistory="true" to all activities.` what? there should be no reason to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you call the `finish()` in MainActivity when you start the your FinalActivity

`noHistory = "true"` should give you the solution, but you can get a similar behavior by calling `finish()` in your MainActivity immediately after it launches a new Activity. However, noHistory is more maintainable in the end, because you may end up forgetting to include the `finish()` call if you add another startActivity() call to your MainActivity later.

Answer (score 0):

You can just start the final activity on top of the A activity and then just invoke finish() in it.

Example:

User is in 'A' activity, he presses the Back button (I assume you overriden the onBackPressed method).
There you start the final activity and if the user presses a button you just invoke finish() and the user is taken back to 'A' activity.

Answer (score 0):

From Android documentation:

> android:noHistory
> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
>
> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

As you have mentioned noHistory tag, there is no back stack maintained by android & activities are getting finish as soon you leave them to start your **final activity**

One solution can be to send launcher activity name while launching final activity. Using this information you can launch launcher activity whenever you need it.

e.g

```
Intent it = new Intent(this,FinalActivity.class);
it.putExtra("launched_from",this.getClass().getSimpleName());
startActivity(it);
```

You can get retrieve it in FinalActivity like this

```
String launched_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("launched_from");
```

Now you know from which activity it got launched.